# how to get all cookies stored in the browser when using with Bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, browser, bookmarklet

I am developing a bookmarklet using Javascript. When clicked on that bookmarklet I need to know whether the user is logged into my website. For that I am using cookies functionality , whether the cookie is stored.
To get all the cookies from browser and find whether the user logged in i am using this code .

`

```
 var getCookies = function(){
  var pairs = document.cookie.split(";");
  var cookies = {};
  for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++){
    var pair = pairs[i].split("=");
    cookies[pair[0]] = unescape(pair[1]);
  }
  return cookies;
}

var myCookies = getCookies();
console.log("cookies secret is -  "+myCookies.secret); // "Getting undefined here"
console.log("cookies  are -  "+JSON.stringify(myCookies)); // "display all cookies so I can know whether user is logged in" `
```

When using this code I am only getting the cookies related to the url I opened when clicking Bookmarklet.

I need to get all the cookies stored in my browser. Please help me fix it.

Comment: you can't do that, from my knowledge

Comment: Is there any other way to find whether user logged in other than cookies?

Comment: hard to say, why don't you do login from the bookmarklet?